# Generating function of binary string with minimum lengths for 0s and 1s

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

a) Show that the generating function by length for binary strings where every block of 0s has length at least 2, each block of ones has length at least 3 is:

$$\frac{(1-x+x^3)(1-x+x^2)}{1-2x+x^2-x^5}$$

b) Give a recurrence relation and enough initial conditions to determine coefficients of power series.

So for a), I came up with the block decomposition $((0^*00)^*(1^*111)^*)^*$ and found the generating function, using the fact that $0\leadsto x$, $1\leadsto x$, and $a^*\leadsto\frac{1}{1-a}$ where a is some binary string:

$$\frac{(1-x)^2}{(1-x-x^2)(1-x-x^3)}$$

which, clearly, does not equal the expected result. Could someone clear up for me where I went wrong?

Also, for b), how would you find a recurrence relation, since the degree of the numerator and denominator are the same, so there would be no general $a_n$ term.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think there are $7$ such strings of length four, namely $0000$, $0001$, $0011$, $1000$, $1001$, $1100$, $1111$.  Your first generating function suggests $2$ while your second suggests $3$

Answer (score 4):

**Generating Function**

We can piece together the generating function as follows
$$
\overbrace{\vphantom{\left(\frac{x^2}1\right)}\ \ \frac1{1-x}\ \ }^{\substack{\text{any number}\\\text{of ones}}}\overbrace{\vphantom{\left(\frac{x^2}1\right)}\frac1{1-\underbrace{\quad\frac{x^2}{1-x}\quad}_{\substack{\text{two or more}\\\text{zeros}}}\underbrace{\quad\frac{x}{1-x}\quad}_{\substack{\text{one or more}\\\text{ones}}}}}^{\substack{\text{any number of blocks of zeros}\\\text{and ones}}}\overbrace{\left(1+\frac{x^2}{1-x}\right)}^{\substack{\text{zero or two or}\\\text{more zeros}}}
$$
The block decomposition is $1^\ast\left(000^\ast11^\ast\right)^\ast\left(()+000^\ast\right)$

Thus, the generating function is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{1-x+x^2}{1-2x+x^2-x^3}}
$$

---

**Recurrence Relation**

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
&1-x+x^2\\
&=\left(1-2x+x^2-x^3\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\\
&=\overbrace{\vphantom{()}\quad\ a_0\quad\ }^1+\overbrace{(a_1-2a_0)}^{-1}\,x+\overbrace{(a_2-2a_1+a_0)}^1\,x^2+\sum_{k=3}^\infty\overbrace{(a_k-2a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}-a_{k-3})}^0\,x^k
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, the recurrence relation is determined by the denominator: $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$, and $a_2=2$, then for $n\ge3$, use
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{a_n=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}}
$$

Comment: I notice that this answer was unaccepted, but no other was accepted. Is there something that is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

robjohn has given a generating function.  Here is a recurrence based approach.

Suppose $b_n$ is the number of strings ending with $0$ and $c_n$ the number ending with $1$, and $a_n=b_n+c_n$ being what you want.  It seems obvious that

1. $a_n=b_n+c_n$ by definition
2. $b_n=b_{n-1}+c_{n-2}$ by adding $0$ to an existing $0$ or $00$ to an existing $1$
3. $c_n=b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$ by adding $1$ to an existing $0$ or $1$

so

4. $c_n=a_{n-1}$ from (3) and (1) and so $c_{n-2}=a_{n-3}$
5. $b_{n-1}=c_n-c_{n-1}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ from (3) and (4) and so $b_{n}=a_{n}-a_{n-1}$
6. $a_{n}-a_{n-1}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$ from (2) and (5) and (4) giving $$a_{n}=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$$

That will lead to a denominator in the generating function of $1-2x+x^2-x^3$

Since $b_1=0, b_2=1, c_1=1, c_2=1$, we can find $a_0=1, a_1=1, a_2=2, a_3=4, a_4=7$ etc. But $\frac{1}{1-2x+x^2-x^3}=1+2x+3x^2+5x^3+9x^4+\cdots$ so we need to subtract $\frac{x}{1-2x+x^2-x^3} = x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+\cdots$ and then add $\frac{x^2}{1-2x+x^2-x^3}= x^2+2x^3+3x^4+\cdots$ to match the coefficients, with a result of $$\frac{1-x+x^2}{1-2x+x^2-x^3}$$ as robjohn found more directly

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ be the number of strings that start with $0$, and let $b_n$ be the number of strings that start with $1$.  Then $a_0=b_0=1$, $a_1=0$, and, by conditioning on the length $k$ of the current run, we see that
\begin{align}
a_n &= \sum_{k=2}^n b_{n-k} &&\text{for $n \ge 2$}\\
b_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n a_{n-k} &&\text{for $n \ge 1$}.
\end{align}
Let $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ and $B(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$.  Then the recurrence relations imply
\begin{align}
A(z)-a_0 -a_1z &=\frac{z^2}{1-z} B(z) \\
B(z)-b_0 &=\frac{z}{1-z} A(z)
\end{align}
Solving for $A(z)$ and $B(z)$ yields
\begin{align}
A(z) &= \frac{1-2z+2z^2-z^3}{1-2z+z^2-z^3}\\
B(z) &= \frac{1-z}{1-2z+z^2-z^3}
\end{align}
So the desired generating function (subtracting the $1z^0=1$ term for the empty string that is otherwise counted twice) is
$$A(z)+B(z)-1=\frac{1-z+z^2}{1-2z+z^2-z^3}.$$